# Disable automatic ID table generation functionality in DJango

Tags: python, django, model, migration

I'm having a problem trying to get my model to generate a migrations with the ID, which I configured inside the model.

```
class Produtos(models.Model):
STATUS_PRODUTOS = [
    ('A', 'Ativo'),
    ('I', 'Inativo'),
]
cod_produto = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True),
nome_produto = models.CharField(max_length=155)
status_produto = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_PRODUTOS)
```

Whenever I give the command to run the migration creation, and I go to check, it's Django's automatic ID.

```
    operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Produtos',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('nome_produto', models.CharField(max_length=155)),
            ('status_produto', models.CharField(choices=[('A', 'Ativo'), ('I', 'Inativo')], max_length=1)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

I need to know how to disable or remove this configuration from my Django, since, as I've already done the primary auth migrations and everything, I won't need this generation anymore;

Comment: remove the trailing comma after the `cod_producto` line.

Comment: Oh, jesus. Man, you are incredible. Thank you, i'll never forget.